# Kotlin Database Error CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, kotlin

This is error, it says index out of bounds, but i couldn't how can i solve it, there are some Turkish words but they aren't important, i think:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.burhanozen.nothesaplama, PID: 26919
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.burhanozen.nothesaplama/com.example.burhanozen.nothesaplama.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at ........
```

I was trying to store some kind of student information. I have these errors, and I share codes below.
This is my MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val fab = findViewById(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton
    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,NotEkrani::class.java)
        startActivity(intent) }


    val studentsArray = ArrayList<String>()

    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,studentsArray)
    listView.adapter= arrayAdapter

    try{

        val myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("student", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null)
        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (isim TEXT," +
                " dersbir TEXT, dersbirkredi TEXT, dersbirort TEXT," +
                " dersiki TEXT, dersikikredi TEXT, dersikiort TEXT) ")

        val cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("select * from students",null)

        val nameIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("isim")
        val dersbirIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersbir")
        val dersbirkrediIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersbirkredi")
        val dersbirortIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersbirort")
        val dersikiIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersiki")
        val dersikikrediIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersikikredi")
        val dersikiortIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("dersikiort")

        cursor.moveToNext()

        while (cursor != null){

            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(nameIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersbirIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersbirkrediIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersbirortIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersikiIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersikikrediIx))
            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(dersikiortIx))

            cursor.moveToNext()

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


        }
        while (cursor!=null){
            cursor!!.close()
        }



    }catch (e:SQLException){

    }
```

And this is my second Activity Page, i couldn't any error here, but may be this can help. I wrote database codes here.

```
fun kaydet(view:View){
    val isim = isim.text.toString()
    val dersbir = dersbir.text.toString()
    val dersbirkredi = dersbirkredi.text.toString()
    val dersbirort = dersbirort.text.toString()
    val dersiki = dersiki.text.toString()
    val dersikikredi = dersikikredi.text.toString()
    val dersikiort = dersikiort.text.toString()

    try {
        val myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("student", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null)

        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (isim TEXT," +
                " dersbir TEXT, dersbirkredi TEXT, dersbirort TEXT," +
                " dersiki TEXT, dersikikredi TEXT, dersikiort TEXT) ")

        val sqlString = "INSERT INTO students (isim,dersbir,dersbirkredi,dersbirort,dersiki,dersikikredi,dersikiort) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        val statement = myDatabase.compileStatement(sqlString)

        statement.bindString(1,isim)
        statement.bindString(2,dersbir)
        statement.bindString(3,dersbirkredi)
        statement.bindString(4,dersbirort)
        statement.bindString(5,dersiki)
        statement.bindString(6,dersikikredi)
        statement.bindString(7,dersikiort)
        statement.execute()


    }catch (e:SQLException){

    }
    val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop to look like this:

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(nameIx))
        ...


    }
```

(Remove all the other `cursor.moveToNext()` from your code)

You are checking for `cursor != null` in your while loop condition, but it won't become null after you read all the rows from cursor.

In the above code, `cursor.moveToNext` returns true if there is a row next. Otherwise returns false and the loop terminates.

And, just noticed, you should change this from,

```
while (cursor!=null){
      cursor!!.close()
}
```

to an if check:

```
if (cursor!=null){
      cursor.close()
}
```

Or, as [Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49746/todd) suggested in the comments, you can use the Higher order function `use` which automatically closes the cursor, which is simlar to Java 7 try-with-resources.

```
cursor.use {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            studentsArray.add(cursor.getString(nameIx))
            ...


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your cursor size is 1. There is only one record in your database. But you are querying database more than 1 time. That is the reason of your Error.

First of all your complete code of execution is wrong.

You are creating a database in your activity. If you do you can't manage your database properly and efficiently.

First, you have to create a SqliteOpenHelper database in a separate class. Then you have to create a table there. Then write helper methods there to get and insert values from it.

Your database class should be like the below example.

```
class DbHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "example.db", null, 4) {
    val TAG = javaClass<DbHelper>().getSimpleName()
    val TABLE = "logs"

    companion object {
        public val ID: String = "_id"
        public val TIMESTAMP: String = "TIMESTAMP"
        public val TEXT: String = "TEXT"
    }

    val DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE + " (" +
        "${ID} integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
        "${TIMESTAMP} integer," +
        "${TEXT} text"+
        ")"

    fun log(text: String) {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(TEXT, text)
        values.put(TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis())
        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE, null, values);
    }

    fun getLogs() : Cursor {
        return getReadableDatabase()
                .query(TABLE, arrayOf(ID, TIMESTAMP, TEXT), null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating: " + DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    }

}
```

Since you are using Kotin database is very easy with **Anko-Sqlite**. By this library storing and retrieving data from the database is so easy. You can check it here.
https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#using-anko-sqlite-in-your-project